# Rolling correlation with 'grouped by' - Error: incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, dplyr, finance, rolling-computation

I'm trying to calculate rolling correlations with a five year window based on daily stock data. My dataframe `test` consists of 20 columns, with `"logRet3"` being located in column #17 and `"logMarRet3"` in #18. I want to calculate the correlation of these two return measures.

What makes it difficult is the fact that I want the rolling correlation to be grouped by my share indicator `"PERMNO"` in column #1. By that I mean that the rolling correlation "restarts" whenever the time-series data of a particular stock ends.

Through research I came up with the following code, using the `dplyr`, `zoo` and `magrittr` packages:

```
test <- test %>% 
  group_by(PERMNO) %>% 
  mutate(CorSecMar = zoo::rollapply(test, width = 1255, function(x) cor(x[,logRet3], x[,logMarRet3]), fill = NA, align = "right"))
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Error in x[,logMarRet3]: Incorrect number of dimensions
```

Me being a newbie, I tried adjusting the code by deleting the `,`:

```
test <- test %>% 
  group_by(PERMNO) %>% 
  mutate(CorSecMar = zoo::rollapply(test, width = 1255, function(x) cor(x[logRet3], x[logMarRet3]), fill = NA, align = "right"))
```

resulting in the following error (translated to English):

```
Error in x[logMarRet3]: Only zeros are allowed to be mixed with negative indices
```

Any help on how to fix these errors or alternative ways of calculating the rolling correlation by group would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks to G. Grothendieck for pointing out some flaws in my question. I'm referring to his answer for reproducible input and will keep that in mind for further posts.

Comment: Did you try `x[, "logRet3"]` ?

Comment: @demarsylvain: I just tried it and it still results in the first error mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems:

- `rollapply` applies to each column separately unless `by.column = FALSE` is used.
- using `test` within `group_by` will not cause `test` to be subsetted.  It will refer to the entire dataset.  Use individual column names instead.
- the column names in the code in the question must have quotes around them; otherwise, it is saying there are variables of those names containing the column names.
- when posting to SO you need to reduce your problem to a complete reproducible example and post that.  I have done it this time for you in the Note at the end.

With reference to the Note, use this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

mycor <- function(x) cor(x[, 1], x[, 2])
DF %>%
  group_by(stock) %>%
  mutate(Cor = rollapplyr(cbind(a, b), 4, mycor, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)) %>%
  ungroup
```

or this code which only uses zoo.  `mycor` is from above.

```
library(zoo)

n <- nrow(DF)
roll <- function(i) rollapplyr(DF[i, c("a", "b")], 4, mycor, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)
transform(DF, Cor = ave(1:n, stock, FUN = roll))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
DF <- data.frame(stock = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 6), a = 1:6, b = (1:6)^3)
```